# Is there a way to use different styles for different kernels in Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter

I have both Python 2 and Python 3 kernels in Jupyter. I would like to use a different style sheet (`custom.css`) for those two so that it is easier for me to tell which environment I am working in. Is this possible?